# initialNavigation enabled only working with angular universal

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-universal

I have a angular app with angular universal enabled and my application is loading twice one on server side second on browser so i have used `initialNavigation: 'enabled'` to avoid flickering.

```
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { initialNavigation: 'enabled' })],
```

After this my `[lazyload]` module stopped working which i am using to lazy load images also change detection is not working. Also its working only after `npm run build:ssr` but when i running app locally with `ng serve` whole app is blank.

can any help how to run change detection, lazy load and app with ng serve.